# .Net Hashtable - Contains vs ContainsKey

Tags: .net, hashtable

I just noticed the HashTable objects have a Contains and CotainsKey method, with same description. So are they just synonyms or is there som edifference behind the scenes

Comment: Good question! `Contains` is there to implement `IDictionary.Contains`, which "determines whether the `IDictionary` object contains an element with the specified key" - so why is `ContainsKey` there?!

Comment: hmm food for thought. Why dont you open a separate question for this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you examine the code of Contains with reflector, you can see that it directly call ContainsKey.

The IL is:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance bool Contains(object key) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldarg.1 
    L_0002: callvirt instance bool System.Collections.Hashtable::ContainsKey(object)
    L_0007: ret 
}
```

This translates to the following C#

```
public virtual bool Contains(object key)
{
    return this.ContainsKey(key);
}
```

Comment: So why ContainsKey is public?

Comment: This answer shows that `Contains` and `ContainsKey` perform the same function, but it doesn't answer why. The most likely answer, which was hinted at by AakashM, is that the only purpose of the `Contains` function is to implement the `IDictionary` interface so hash tables can be interchanged with other dictionary objects.

Comment: Without looking at help or documentation regarding the `Contains` method, it would be unclear as to whether it performs the same function as `ContainsKey` or `ContainsValue`. A better question would be, "Why does the `IDictionary` interface not have a `ContainsKey` method?" since `ContainsKey` isn't obscure.

Comment: The answer that makes the most sense is bad design.

Answer (score 8):

The `Contains` method just calls the `ContainsKey` method internally - you can check this using [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/).

Answer (score 1):

No they behave exactly the same